# Positioning a QPushButton using QGridLayout in a QDialog?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to position a `QPushButton` in a simple application. What I'd like to do is have one single button be centered and at the bottom of my application.

**I do not want to use the designer, so please do not suggest that (this is for my own curiosity).** Here is my code:

```
QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout;
QPushButton* button1 = new QPushButton("button1");
centralWidget->setLayout(layout);
qDebug() << "columns:";
qDebug() << layout->columnCount();
qDebug() << "rows:";
qDebug() << layout->rowCount();
button1->setFixedSize(100, 50);
layout->addWidget(button1,2,0,1,1,Qt::AlignCenter);
```

So, there are a few things I'm curious about here.

First, when I do a `columnCount()` and a `rowCount()`, it comes back with `1` for each. If I'm going to be setting the row and column position of the button in the grid, I'm obviously not going to want a 1x1 grid. How do I change this?

Second, what if I want an empty row? Do I have to use a spacer for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't like to use designer, but you can still use it to see what it comes up with! I mean, you can set the view you have in mind there, if you know how, and then check the code the `uic` generates, to find out how you can do it yourself. ;)

Comment: How would I go about viewing the `uic` file? I can view the `.ui` file for it, but it's in XML, which is less than ideal to review.

Comment: After building your project, there will be a uifilename_ui.h file beside it. see that file.

Answer (score 0):

> First, when I do a columnCount() and a rowCount(), it comes back with
>   1 for each. If I'm going to be setting the row and column position of
>   the button in the grid, I'm obviously not going to want a 1x1 grid.
>   How do I change this?

There is no problem with adding a widget into the grid on the position let's say: *row=20* *column=20*, if the grid's size is only *1* x *1*. It just creates an empty cells (with the *zero* size) filing the unused rows and columns.

> Second, what if I want an empty row? Do I have to use a spacer for
>   that?

Yes, if you want an empty row or column, you have to put a spacer (`QSpacerItem`) or an empty widget (a plain `QWidget`) into one of it's cells. You have to set a fixed width or height for this spacer (or widget) if you want a row/column of fixed height/width.

Answer (score 0):

*First, when I do a columnCount() and a rowCount(), it comes back with 1 for each. If I'm going to be setting the row and column position of the button in the grid, I'm obviously not going to want a 1x1 grid. How do I change this?*

Yes, can fix this to add a QSpacerItem to row 0 and 1.

*Second, what if I want an empty row? Do I have to use a spacer for that?*

Yes, you can use a QSpacerItem for it.